# sed script extended regex

Tags: regex, linux, unix, sed

I need to write multiple `sed` script files. I can't seem to find a way to enable extended regex from within the script. Is this possible? It isn't possible for me to use option flags because the scripts need to run on an external environment which isn't under my control.

Comment: Does it have to be `sed`? Also, you might get better responses over at http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I believe the only programmable switch feature within a sed script is the `-n` switch, which may be turned on if the first two characters of the script begin `#n`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try specifying the flag in the script shebang, say:

```
#!/bin/sed -rf
# script goes here
```

And then tell the admin to run the script as is (`chmod a+x` it first, then `./script.sed`) so the shebang line is used for finding the right interpreter.

You may need to substitute `/bin/sed` with the right path for your environment. Unfortunately you probably won't be able to use `/usr/bin/env sed -r` for this (the extra `-r` is a problem).

Comment: I think you need -rf.. maybe?

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer to your question is "no", *but*, if this is GNU `sed`, then you probably don't really *need* extended regular expressions, because GNU `sed`'s implementation of basic regular expressions actually supports the features of EREs that true POSIX BREs don't. Admittedly, the result is incredibly, painfully backslash-heavy — ERE's `s/(a|b+|cd?)/e/g` becomes BRE's `s/\(a\|b\+\|cd\?\)/e/g` — but it works.