# Making all the decimals equal with sed

Tags: csv, sed, decimal

I have a csv file with this structure:

```
123;rr;2;RRyO, chess mobil;pio;25.766;1;0;24353;21.6;;S
1243;rho;9;RpO, chess yext cat;downpio;67.98;1;0;237753;25.34600;;S
```

I want all the numbers of a specific column to have only 2 decimals (adding or removing decimals).

With this output

```
123;rr;2;RRyO, chess mobil;pio;25.766;1;0;24353;21.60;;S
1243;rho;9;RpO, chess yext cat;downpio;67.98;1;0;237753;25.34;;S
```

I have tried this, but doesnt work

`sed 's/[[:digit:]]*\.//g' data.csv`

Any idea?

Maybe a script is needed?

Comment: Why are you writing 25.34600 as 25.34 instead of the more natural 25.35?  Is that intentional, or a mistake in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -F\; -ne '$F[9] = sprintf "%.2f", $F[9]; print join ";", @F' -- file.csv
```

Note that it will set the value on line 2 to `25.35`, not `25.34`, as that's how `%f` rounds `25.346`.

You can use

```
$F[9] = sprintf "%.2f", int($F[9] * 100) / 100
```

to get the output you want.

In sed, you need to distinguish the two cases: there's only a single deciaml, or there're more than two.

```
sed -E 's/(;[0-9]+)\.([0-9])(;[^;]*;[^;]*)$/\1.\20\3/' \
    -E 's/(;[0-9]+)\.([0-9]{2})[0-9]+(;[^;]*;[^;]*)$/\1.\2\3/'
```

Comment: Hi, is it possible do it with sed? I am not used to use perl and I do not know its syntaxis for further lines

Comment: @JoanSerrano: Updated. But I'm not sure it's more readable than the Perl solution.

Comment: Many thanks choroba, I am trying to write it in a .sed file without succeful... Can you help me, please? I tried the commandas in the console and works perfectly, vut I wanna make a script. Many thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your additional question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/9282123/1030675

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '{$(NF-2) = sprintf( "%0.2f", $(NF-2))}1' FS=\; OFS=\; input
123;rr;2;RRyO, chess mobil;pio;25.766;1;0;24353;21.60;;S
1243;rho;9;RpO, chess yext cat;downpio;67.98;1;0;237753;25.35;;S
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/^/;/;s/;[0-9]*\.[0-9]*/&00/g;s/(;[0-9]*\.[0-9]{2})[^;]*/\1/g;s/.//' file
```

Prepend a csv delimiter to the start of the line so that global regexp will match successfully.

If a field looks like a decimal; append two `0`'s.

If a field looks like a decimal; shorten it to two decimal places.

Remove the introduced csv delimiter.

N.B. This does not account for rounding.

---

If rounding is required perhaps:

```
sed -E 's/^/;/;s/;([0-9]*\.[0-9]*)/$(printf ";%.2f" \1)/g;s/.(.*)/echo "\1"/e' file
```